# Creating plots from Excel time serial numbers

Tags: r, excel, time

I have data of tide heights obtained every 15 minutes for a period of two years (2012-2013), in this format: time 41000, 41000.01042, 41000.02083, etc; height 1.813, 1.802, 1.774, etc

The time serial number is from Excel, which I understand as being the number of days after January 1, 1900. I wish to plot the data in R with the date on the x-axis and height on the y-axis. Can someone please advice on how this is best done? Thanks.

Comment: `as.Date(41000, origin =  '1899-12-30')` You can convert them to dates like this.

Comment: or use read_excel function in package readxl to import Excel data with dates intact.  You will then need to force_tz() in package lubridate to assign the correct time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows then this would work for you:

```
as.POSIXct(as.Date(41000.02083,origin="1899-12-30"))

> "2012-03-31 20:29:59 EDT" #This has been converted based on my local timezone
```

On Mac you need a different `origin="1904-01-01"`.

I made this example data-set:

```
datenum <- c(41000, 41000.01042, 41000.02083)
height  <- c(2.813, 1.802, 0.774) #Edit the heights to make it visually appealing
df <- data.frame(cbind(datenum = datenum, height=height))
```

Then add a column with proper date-time formatting:

```
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(df$datenum,origin="1899-12-30")) #Origin for windows excel
```

And plotted the bar chart:

```
barplot(df$height,names.arg=df$Date,col="lightblue")
```

This would be the graph:

[image]